# YouTube 502 Error on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, youtube

this started 3 days ago, and it seems it is not going away. I don't know what to do, other than searching for solutions on web, and I am not a computer pro or geek type. Is this problem related with my computer or is it a YouTube related one? All the other computers in the house are doing the same. I restarted my modem many times though it didn't help. I would like to get an answer on that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I could be useful to tell which web browser do you use. Other web servers work correctly? 502 error code says that there is an error on the server. It is weird that it happens for 3 days.

Comment: I am using Chrome, Firefox, and Opera; none of them displays the page. Another notebook in the house also does the same thing. Other web servers? You mean other webpages? If so, they work okay. Only YouTube is doing this. Very strange. I am clueless. Hoping that it is a YouTube based problem, otherwise I don't want to format my computers, cause it would be a great loss of time.

Comment: You can try accessing youtube from a different address by going through a proxy. Here http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-225434 you can find some open proxies. For example this one is working for me just now 84.22.2.1:8080. Be aware of the fact that using similar proxies could be **very dangerous**. They can steal you your password or other sensitive information. Create a new user profile in your browser or remove all cookies before connecting through such a proxy. If you ever decide to send something sensitive (password) through such a proxy, connect only through HTTPS. to be continued

Comment: and the certificate must be trusted.

Comment: Seriously, do NOT reformat the computer;  that's a complete waste of time in this case.

Comment: Debra can you mail me at ilkergorusun@gmail.com so I can send you an image which shows the result of the trace www.youtube.com command? I don't understand anything from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

502 is a "bad gateway" error.  So the most likely cause is associated with Youtube itself, second would be an issue with your internet provider.  You may have to just wait it out.

I find it a bit ironic that there is a video posted on Youtube telling you how to fix a Youtube 502 problem.

Note that the problem can be absent from a different geographic location or internet provider, depending on what Youtube hardware you hit vs what went down.

Sometimes it helps to check here:
http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/youtube.com.html
but in this case, the site reports Youtube down 21 hrs ago, but not now (and, indeed, it's up for -me-).  However, that will only really tell you if the website is down completely;  websites like Youtube, which have multiple servers etc., can readily be working for one person & not for another.

Comment: Thank you very much Debra. I live in Turkey, and none of my friends have this problem at the moment. I think I'll wait. I contacted my ISP, but they offered me some VPN solutions since they have no problem from their side. Well, I hope it gets fixed soon. Thanks again, have a nice day.

Comment: @İlkerGörüşün: Do your friends use the same ISP?

Comment: Yes @pabouk, they do.

Comment: Ah, well then access from the middle of the US is almost meaningless here. But with every computer in the house seeing same, it's likely a bit of hardware between your router & their servers. If time doesn't resolve it, then something is blocking it. I assume you aren't using a router between computer & ISP "gateway" -- if you are, connect instead directly to the ISP device, to test -- and check w/the ISP to see how to verify that their gateway device ("modem") isn't blocking it too. Can you even ping youtube?

Comment: I just did and it gave me a "Request Timed Out". This is really frustrating. I wish I was an expert :) I don't know what to do at the moment.

Comment: That would be consistent with the error you saw, though. And you're just using the ISP's device, not a router of your own? Also make sure if you restart the router that you keep it completely unplugged (network & power) for a few minutes, which may up the odds of getting a different address, thus possible route. You can also use "tracert www.youtube.com" which will pinpoint where the problem lies, and your ISP should've had you trie that.

Comment: Here is an example of troubleshooting.  http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r8904462-Gateway-timeout-error-504-   Also, make sure that the DNS servers are correct, that they're not manually set on the computers but using the ISPs or a standard reliable open DNS server for fallback, as the ISP might've changed their DNS server address(es). Most ISP hardware in the US includes an internal utility to run a ping from the device itself. [and it's too late for me to edit the comment above to fix "trie"!]